# PHP preg_replace numeric backreference not working

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I am trying to wrap numbers inside a given string in a `<span>`.

`$datitle = "hey hey 13"`;

`$datitle = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '<span class="title-number">$1</span>', $datitle);`

However that returns:

`hey hey <span class="title-number"></span><span class="title-number"></span>`

With two empty spans, without the number inside.

What I want to get is:

`hey hey <span class="title-number">13</span>`

How do I use the number matched by `preg_replace` as a backreference?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `/[0-9]/` means `One number from 0 to 9`. This means `1` fits your regexp, `3` fits your regexp. Not `13`.

Second - items which are not wrapped in a `()` are not stored as a result of regexp. But `full` regexp is stored in `$0`.

So proper code is:

```
$datitle = "hey hey 13";
$datitle = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)/', '<span class="title-number">$1</span>', $datitle);
echo $datitle; // hey hey <span class="title-number">13</span>
```

Or:

```
$datitle = "hey hey 13";
$datitle = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '<span class="title-number">$0</span>', $datitle);
echo $datitle; // hey hey <span class="title-number">13</span>
```